# How to create generic function Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, tsx

Is is possible to create generic function Components?

I assumed that something like next example would have done the trick:

```
type MyComponentProps<T> = T & {
    component: ComponentType<T>, 
    primary?: boolean, 
    size?: 'S' | 'M' | 'L'
}


const MyComponent: ComponentType<MyComponentProps<T>> = ({ component, size, primary,...rest }) => {
    /* ... */
}
```

... but not

When declaring the component as function and leaving out the React.ComponentType declaration the declaration seems to be fine:

```
function MyComponent<T>({ size, primary, component, ...rest }: MyComponentProps<T>) {
    /* ... */
}
```

But writing the Component like so, TSX (I'm using latest create-react-app) does not recognize the it as a Component anymore, because it is missing the React.ComponentType declaration I assume.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally used:

```
type MyComponentProps<T> = T & {
    component: ComponentType<T>, 
    primary?: boolean, 
    size?: 'S' | 'M' | 'L'
}
type MyGenericComponent = <T>(p: MyComponentProps<T>) => ReactElement | null;

const MyComponent: MyGenericComponent = (props) => { ... }
```

Not very elegant but works. Still React does not fully recognize the function is a Component, but intellisense related to correct props check seem to work.

To my understanding, the reason it's so complicated to create generic function components with typescript seems to boil down to that typescript does not support 'higher kinded types'.